Youtube's LiveStream API failing with error "invalidDescription" when in Hindi
I want to create an event on Youtube where details should be in Hindi.
I am creating an event on YT using broadcast API where my title's length is 100 and description length is 4996, the language is Hindi.
Broadcast API is working fine, and it creates an event on YT.
Now for streaming i am using liveStream API and adding snippet.title and snippet.description of same length as above.
Expected Result: LiveStream API should be created successfully since the allowed length for description is 10000 and my length is 4996.
Here are my inputs:
Title: विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैगटैगग विभ
Description: विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न. विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न  विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का परीक्षणविभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ विभिन्न भाषा शीर्षक विवरण और टैग के साथ वनस्ट्रीम का'
Here is the error log:
unable to create live stream - [
  {
    message: "Description can't be longer than 10000 characters",
    domain: 'youtube.liveStream',
    reason: 'invalidDescription',
    extendedHelp: 'https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#snippet.description'
  }
]

Here is the broadcast API payload and endpoint:
const broadcastParams = {
            "auth": this._oauth2Client,
            "part": broadcastData.part,
            "resource": {
                "snippet": {
                    "title": broadcastData.title,
                    "description": broadcastData.description,
                    "scheduledStartTime": broadcastData.scheduledStartTime,
                    "scheduledEndTime": broadcastData.scheduledEndTime,
                },
                "status": {
                    "privacyStatus": broadcastData.privacyStatus,
                    "selfDeclaredMadeForKids":broadcastData.selfDeclaredMadeForKids
                },
                "contentDetails": {
                    "enableDvr": broadcastData.enableDvr,
                    "enableArchive": broadcastData.enableArchive,
                    // "recordFromStart": broadcastData.recordFromStart,
                    "monitorStream": {
                        "enableMonitorStream": broadcastData.enableMonitorStream,
                    },
                    "enableAutoStart": true
                }

            }
        };

        // if schedule is 360 based video - set event as 360 degree
        if (broadcastData.isVR) {
            broadcastParams.resource.contentDetails.projection = '360';
        }

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            // Create Broadcast Stream
            YouTube.liveBroadcasts.insert(broadcastParams, (error: any, broadcast: any) => {
                if (error) {
                    if (error.errors) reject(error.errors);
                    else reject(error);
                } else {
                    resolve(broadcast.data);
                }
            });
        });

Here is the liveStream's API payload and endpoint:
const liveStreamData = {
  part: "snippet, cdn, contentDetails",
  title: title,
  description: description || "",
  resolution: "variable",
  frameRate: "variable",
  ingestionType: "rtmp",
  isReusable: false,
};

const liveStreamParams = {
  auth: this._oauth2Client,
  part: liveStreamData.part,
  resource: {
    snippet: {
      title: liveStreamData.title,
      description: liveStreamData.description,
    },
    cdn: {
      resolution: liveStreamData.resolution,
      frameRate: liveStreamData.frameRate,
      ingestionType: liveStreamData.ingestionType,
    },
    contentDetails: { isReusable: liveStreamData.isReusable },
  },
};

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  YouTube.liveStreams.insert(liveStreamParams, (error, result) => {
    if (error) {
      if (error.errors) reject(error.errors);
      else reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(result.data);
    }
  });
});


When encoded in UTF-8 your description is 13,000+ bytes. I'd guess that's what they're counting.

I think you need to talk to YouTube's API support directly though. They'll be able to give you a definite answer.

The Live Streaming API Support page says they monitor questions tagged [tag:youtube-livestreaming-api]. If you want help from Google I'd add that back.

Thank you @Rup for taking out the time to respond to my query.
Yes, i think thats the case, can you please redirect me to where i can talk to the API support team?
